# jQuery UI Resize cursor handler position bug with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, resize

I did a lot of test and the jQuery UI cursor position on resize seem to be dephased with Bootstrap.

The cursor is not perfectly aligned, too much on right when adding bootstrap css

I did some test here,

```
.resizable
```

Without Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/5jk2x87m/1/

The same thing with Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/5jk2x87m/9/

```
.resizable
```

Comment: the `css` is not the same in the two codes

Comment: The cursor is not perfectly aligned, too much on right, the diference append when i add bootstrap.